# array multidimensional javascript

Tags: javascript, array, aplicação-web

Eu to com uma seguinte duvida. Vou simplificar o máximo que eu puder para vocês entenderem. 
Estou desenvolvendo um jogo e tenho um array com os valores. Esse array é multidimensional:

```
var valores = [["jaguatirica", "onça-pintada", "suçuarana"],["sabia","canario"],["pacu", "lambari"]]
```

E tenho outro array multidimensional com os caminhos da imagem:

```
var img = [["jaguatirica.jpg", "onça-pintada.jpg", "suçuarana.jpg"],["sabia.jpg","canario.jpg"],["pacu.jpg", "lambari.jpg"]]
```

Quero transformar esse dois arrays em um só:

```
var resultado = [valores[0][0], img[0][0]]
```

que tera como resultado: jaguatirica, jaguatirica.png.

Mas quero que todos os valores se junte com suas respectivas imagens. Me ajudem por favor, é um jogo educativo e será utilizado em escolas municipais. 
[link do jogo em desenvolvimento](http://ayumetech.com.br/jogo-forca)

Comment: Está usando javascript puro (segundo a tag usada) ou tem um jQuery rodando também?

Comment: Só está o javascript puro mesmo

Comment: Certo. Coloque a resposta certa aqui no @TheProHands, pois ele respondeu o que iria dizer: faça um `for` percorrer um array e juntar com o outro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para juntar todos valores e suas respectivas imagens você terá que percorrer cada elemento de cada array e puxar para a array `resultado`.

```
var resultado = [];

for(var i = 0, ln = valores.length; i < ln; i ++) {
    for(var b = 0, len = valores[i].length; b < len; b ++) {
        resultado.push([
            valores[i][b],
            img[i][b]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não consigo retornar nenhum valor no console.log. Obs, só mudei as variaveis

`var resultado = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
              for (var b = 0; i < categories[i].length; b++) {
                resultado.push([
                  categories[i][b],img[i][b]
                  ]);
              }
          }
console.log(resultado)
`

Comment: @LuisCarlosdeSouzaMuniz Para mim, quando chamei `console.log` em seguida, pelo menos em alguns sites, printou o objeto de forma diferente, mas funcionou no JsFiddle. Não entendo, mas isso não afeta o objeto. Ele funciona.

Comment: @LuisCarlosdeSouzaMuniz De qualquer forma vai resultar no mesmo memorizar ou não o tamanho de uma array em um loop e é melhor memorizar o tamanho, assim a array não será re-calculada enquanto o loop executa, e assim a performance do jogo será melhor. Porém, parecem ter dito que navegadores modernos já armazenam o tamanho de uma array em sí na propriedade `length`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e pelo exemplo. vou usá-lo para mais códigos aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Em navegadores modernos e partindo do principio que ambos os arrays estão alinhados tanto em conteúdo como em estrutura pode-se usar o método [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), que cria um novo array concatenando todos elementos dos sub-array, para uniformizar os dados e facilitar a confecção do resultado:

```js
let val = [
  ["jaguatirica", "onça-pintada", "suçuarana"],
  ["sabia", "canario"],
  ["pacu", "lambari"]
];
let img = [
  ["jaguatirica.jpg", "onça-pintada.jpg", "suçuarana.jpg"],
  ["sabia.jpg", "canario.jpg"],
  ["pacu.jpg", "lambari.jpg"]
];

let result = [];                           //Cria o array que receberá o resultado da operação.
let val2 = val.flat();                     //Cria uma array unidimensional a partir dos elementos de val.
let img2 = img.flat();                     //Cria uma array unidimensional a partir dos elementos de img.

//Itera pelos índices de um dos arrays presumindo que val2 e img2 estejam alinhados em tamanho e conteúdo...
for (var i = 0; i < val2.length; i++) {
  result.push([val2[i], img2[i]]);         //... adiciona ao resultado um array com os elementos correspondentes em val2 e img2.
}

console.log(result);                       //Imprime o resultado.
```

Em [navegadores mais antigos ou navegadores OEM](https://caniuse.com/array-flat)  `Array.prototype.flat()` não está disponível então use um [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Polyfill).

```js
let val = [
  ["jaguatirica", "onça-pintada", "suçuarana"],
  ["sabia", "canario"],
  ["pacu", "lambari"]
];
let img = [
  ["jaguatirica.jpg", "onça-pintada.jpg", "suçuarana.jpg"],
  ["sabia.jpg", "canario.jpg"],
  ["pacu.jpg", "lambari.jpg"]
];

let result = [];                           
let val2 = val.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []); 
let img2 = img.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);                     
for (var i = 0; i < val2.length; i++) {
  result.push([val2[i], img2[i]]);         
}

console.log(result);
```