# Como declarar uma chave de Array MultiDimensional - Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Ola, 
Gostaria de saber como eu faço para concatenar duas chaves de um array, a ideia seria mais ou menos assim:

```
dados['azul'][i] = id;
```

Em que o Array dados possui a chave que é uma cor pré definida e a sua segunda chave é um i incrementado com o valor de ID e tudo isso dentro de um for...

Cade vez que ele entrar no laço ele irá fazer um case para adicionar o valor do ID do elemento dentro da chave correta. 
Caso seja da cor esperada, azul por exemplo, ele irá adicionar um novo valor ao array, no entanto serão adicionados vários outros valores, conforme o laço for executado.

O resultado seria algo assim:

```
dados[azul]{
  [2] = valordeID;
  [1] = valordeID;
}
dados[preto]{
  [2] = valordeID;
  [1] = valordeID;
}
```

E assim sucessivamente, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [array multidimensional javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140466/array-multidimensional-javascript)

Comment: A marcada como duplicata não resolveu?

Answer (score 1):

Se o que você quer é um Objeto que guarde um Valor e tenha uma Chave, acredito que você possa usar um [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) .

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('azul', seuArray);
```

Comment: Na realidade eu acho que isso não funcionaria, pois a ideia é que sejam acrescentados vários valores a uma cor e não um array pronto.